# can I access previous versions of publishing pages via '_vti_history/...'?

Tags: 2007, publishing, versioning

I'm not sure what I should be expecting when trying to access a version url of a publishing page.

I can see that there is a Url property of SPListItemVersion for publishing items in the page library, eg; _vti_history/1024/Pages/Extension-type.aspx. But I get a 404 when trying to hit the page.

Should I be expecting this to work? All the documentation I've found refers to document libraries.

Thanks,

Dan.